# Error Key properties cannot be empty

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, jboss-esb

```
Hi all i'm try to deploy a esb project into jboss server 5.1ga 
But i got this error 

**My Enviroment is 
Jboss 5.1 ga,
Jboss Developer Studio 5.0**
Jboss esb 4.11
Riftsaw 2.3.0




 17:58:49,155 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vfszip:/D:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/Save_Event2.esb/ state=Not Installed mode=Manual requiredState=Parse
        org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Key properties cannot be empty
            at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.deployers.mc.EsbConfigParser.getDependenciesFromDeploymentXml(EsbConfigParser.java:265)
            at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.deployers.mc.EsbConfigParser.parse(EsbConfigParser.java:170)
            at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.deployers.mc.EsbConfigParser.parse(EsbConfigParser.java:83)
            at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parseAndInit(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:256)
            at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parse(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:239)
            at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:355)
            at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:322)
            at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:294)
            at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.deploy(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:234)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
            at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
            at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
            at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        Caused by: javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Key properties cannot be empty
            at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(Unknown Source)
            at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.deployers.mc.EsbConfigParser.getDependenciesFromDeploymentXml(EsbConfigParser.java:247)
            ... 38 more
```

That is error I Got  and i'm trying to pass bpel result to esb and back to bpes .

---My deployment.xml-----------------

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <jbossesb-deployment>

 <depends>jboss.esb.quickstart.destination:service=Queue,name=quickstart_helloworld_Request_    esb_reply</depends>
      <depends>quickstart_helloworld_Request_esb</depends>
      <depends>quickstart_helloworld_Request_gw</depends>
    </jbossesb-deployment>
```

--My jbm-queue-service.xml-----------

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <server>
            <mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService"
                name="jboss.esb.quickstart.destination:service=Queue,name=quickstart_helloworld_Request_esb_reply"
                xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Queue-xmbean.xml">
                <depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer
                </depends>
                <depends>jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice</depends>
            </mbean>
            <mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService"
                name="jboss.esb.quickstart.destination:service=Queue,name=quickstart_helloworld_Request_esb"
                xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Queue-xmbean.xml">
                <depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer
                </depends>
                <depends>jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice</depends>
            </mbean>
            <mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService"
                name="jboss.esb.quickstart.destination:service=Queue,name=quickstart_helloworld_Request_gw"
                xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Queue-xmbean.xml">
                <depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer
                </depends>
                <depends>jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice</depends>
            </mbean>
        </server>
```

----My jboss-esb.xml-----------

```
 <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
    <jbossesb
        xmlns="http://anonsvn.labs.jboss.com/labs/jbossesb/trunk/product/etc/schemas/xml/jbossesb-1.0.1.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://anonsvn.labs.jboss.com/labs/jbossesb/trunk/product/etc/schemas/xml/jbossesb-1.0.1.xsd http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossesb/trunk/product/etc/schemas/xml/jbossesb-1.0.1.xsd"
        parameterReloadSecs="5">

        <providers>
            <jms-provider name="JBossMQ" connection-factory="ConnectionFactory">
                <jms-bus busid="quickstartGwChannel">
                    <jms-message-filter dest-type="QUEUE"
                        dest-name="queue/quickstart_helloworld_Request_gw" />
                </jms-bus>
                <jms-bus busid="quickstartEsbChannel">
                    <jms-message-filter dest-type="QUEUE"
                        dest-name="queue/quickstart_helloworld_Request_esb" />
                </jms-bus>
                <jms-bus busid="quickstartEsbReplyChannel">
                    <jms-message-filter dest-type="QUEUE"
                        dest-name="queue/quickstart_helloworld_Request_esb_reply" />
                </jms-bus>

            </jms-provider>
            <jbr-provider name="JBR-Http-1" protocol="http" host="localhost">
                <jbr-bus busid="Http-1" port="8088" />
            </jbr-provider>

        </providers>

        <services>
            <service category="FirstServiceESB" name="SimpleListener"
                description="Hello World">
                <listeners>
                    <jms-listener name="JMS-Gateway" busidref="quickstartGwChannel"
                        is-gateway="true" />
                    <jms-listener name="helloWorld" busidref="quickstartEsbChannel" />
                    <jbr-listener name="Http-Gateway" busidref="Http-1"
                        is-gateway="true" />
                </listeners>
                <actions mep="RequestResponse">
                    <action name="action1"
                        class="MyJMSListenerAction"
                        process="displayMessage" />
                        <!-- 
                    <action name="action2" class="org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.SystemPrintln">
                        <property name="printfull" value="false" />
                    </action>
                    The next action is for Continuous Integration testing 
                    <action name="testStore" class="org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.TestMessageStore" />
                    -->
                </actions>
            </service>
        </services>

    </jbossesb>
```

Any help Appreciated.
    Best Regards,
    Pradeep.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the stacktrace of the error you can see that the error is a MalformedObjectNameException coming from EsbConfigParser:

```
org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.deployers.mc.EsbConfigParser.getDependenciesFromDeploymentXml(EsbConfigParser.java:247)
```

The method name where the error is thrown is

> getDependenciesFromDeploymentXml

So it looks like the problem is in the deployment xml.

Now we can confirm this by looking at the source code of the class (https://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/JBoss/jbossesb-4.7/org/jboss/soa/esb/listeners/deployers/mc/EsbConfigParser.java.htm) and see that it is doing this:

```
    Iterator depends = MetaData.getChildrenByTagName(jboss, "depends");
    if (depends != null)
    {
        while (depends.hasNext())
        {
            Element depend = (Element) depends.next();
            dependencies.add(new ObjectName(MetaData.getElementContent(depend)));
        }
    }
```

And then if we look at your deployment.xml above there is indeed an element that looks invalid:

```
  <depends>jboss.esb.quickstart.destination:service=Queue,name=quickstart_helloworld_Request_    esb_reply</depends>
```

"quickstart_helloworld_Request_   esb_reply" should not have a space between "Request_" and "esb_reply".

Change it to "quickstart_helloworld_Request_esb_reply".